# Why is int raising a TypeError instead of NotImplemented?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I want to write a class which emulates a numeric data type. My new type provides a `__add__` and `__radd__` method. Adding object of this type like `a+b` works fine, also `a+1` works.

My problem is that when I try to use `1+a` the add function of `int` is called which raises a TypeError, so that the interpreter stops, and does not try to call my `__radd__` which would work.

The [python doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) states that "If one of those methods [i.e. `__add__` and `__radd__`] does not support the operation with the supplied arguments, it should return NotImplemented". Why is `int` no raising NotImplemented? And is there a way to fix this without making my class a subclass of int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the numeric model is correct:

```
>>> class Foob(object):
...     def __add__(self, o): return 1
...     def __radd__(self, o): return 2
... 
>>> f = Foob()
>>> f + f
1
>>> f + 5
1
>>> 5 + f
2
```

Your `__radd__` code must eventually be raising a `TypeError` - possibly by calling `int`'s `+` with an incorrect type. What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: yes, you are right. This works in python3. I just discovered that this does not work in ipython for python3! This means my problem was caused by ipython.